# Deploying a basic Symfony app using Magallanes

Tags: symfony, deployment

Working on a simple Symfony application to demonstrate a continuous delivery pipeline. However, I can't get my deployment done using [Magallanes](http://magephp.com). After deployment is finished, I need to manually run `bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` every time. I have the following environment configuration:

```
#production
deployment:
  user: root
  from: ./
  to: /var/www/foo/
  excludes:
  strategy: rsync
releases:
  enabled: false
  max: 2
  symlink: current
  directory: releases
hosts:
  - foo
tasks:
  pre-deploy:
  on-deploy:
  post-release:
  post-deploy:
    - composer/install
    - general/manually:
      - HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E \'[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx\' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
    - general/manually:
      - setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
    - general/manually:
      - setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
    - general/manually:
      - chmod +x bin/console
    - general/manually:
      - bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

As you can see, a lot of manual tasks to get the permissions right. The error I receive when I visit my page is as followed:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/omnia/var/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied'`

I was hoping that my tasks would fix this permission issue, in particular the last one, where I call `cache:clear`.

What to do?

Comment: I used to use Magallanes, but ran into the same issues you are, it was hell. Many times, it's out of Magallanes control. The best solution is to ensure that the user who installed and runs apache, php, composer, ssh and own www directory are the same.

Comment: @DonOmondi Thank you for sharing your experience with Magallanes. I indeed found out it was a difficult thing to execute and have downgraded my Symfony3 app to Symfony2. This made it easier, as Magallanes' support is more compatible with Symfony2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know magallanes.
At the end of your script, you could set the right of www-data to the `app/logs/*` and `app/cache`.  like

```
chmod www-data -r app/logs app/cache
```

If you prefer to use the commandline you have to use --no-warmup for symfony to not create anything. It will not solve the problem of the log though

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup --env=prod
```